# Iterating through a 2 dimensional array in a cascading fashion to sort into a one dimensional array

Tags: arrays, sorting

So let's say I have a 2 dimensional array:

```
1A  2A  3A  4A
1B  2B  3B  4B
1C  2C  3C  4C
1D  2D  3D  4D
1E  2E  3E  4E
```

I want to iterate through this 2-d array, and create a new 1 dimensional array like this:

```
1A, 2A, 1B, 3A, 2B, 1C, etc...
```

To visualize it better,

```
1A 

2A
1B

3A
2B
1C

4A
3B
2C
1D

4B
3C
2D
1E

4C
3D
2E

4D
3E

4E
```

Does anybody have a good solution for this?

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Objective-C, but I figured a solution would be relevant in any language.  Right now all I have is traversing through the first object in each array, then the second object, etc.  but I want to make it cascade like described, I just can't wrap my head around a solid dynamic solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just some pseudo code but it seems to work:

```
X=0;
y=1;
out = array[0][0]
while ( (X!=MAX) && (y!=MAX) ) // MAX = maximum size of the array and assumes a square array //
{
    yy=y;
    xx=x;
    while ( (X!yy) && (y!=xx) )
    {
        out = array[xx][yy]
        XX = XX + 1
        yy = YY + 1
    }
    out = array[xx][yy]
    if (y != MAX)
        y = y + 1
    else
        x = x + 1
}
out = array[MAX][MAX]
```